# VBA - Copy specific cell from all files within a folder and pasting each file copied column as a separate column in a master table

Tags: excel, vba, copy, autofilter

VBA - Copy specific cell from all files within a folder and pasting each file copied column as a separate column in a master table

I have alot of files with a single sheet (sometimes the sheets are named different but they contain similar data arrangement).
I need to copy a specific column from every workbook in folder and each of these copied columns need to be tabulated into a master table as seperate columns.
Also i would need the file name as the header for each column where the value was copied from

xls files are the file type

Comment: SO is intended to assist people when they get stuck with a problem while they are developing their own code. Merely indicating what you 'need' will not get you over the finish line. Try to research the topic on SO and see how others have solved similar issues and from there put your own code together and try it out. If you get stuck you can post the question here and people will be more than willing to assist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Sub FromAllFilesIntoColumns()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceCcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim Cnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    Cnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next
                Set sourceRange = mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all rows then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Rows.Count >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceCcount = sourceRange.Columns.Count

                    If Cnum + SourceCcount >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough columns in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in the first row
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(1, Cnum). _
                                    Resize(, .Columns.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.cells(2, Cnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        Cnum = Cnum + SourceCcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: how do i add code, im having trouble

Comment: how do i modify the code to copy column k into a master column, below the header file name of the master table i want to paste values

Answer (score 0):

### Import Columns

```vb
Sub ImportColumns()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test"
    Const SOURCE_WORKSHEET_ID As Variant = 1 ' the first (you say: 'and only')
    Const SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS  As String = "A2"
    Const SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.xls" ' only `.xls`
    
    Const DESTINATION_WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Master"
    Const DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    
    ' Write the source file paths to a collection.
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    
    Dim sPath As String: sPath = SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> pSep Then sPath = sPath & pSep
    Dim sFolderName As String: sFolderName = Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)
    If Len(sFolderName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path '" & sPath & "' doesn't exist.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim sDirPattern As String: sDirPattern = sPath & SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sDirPattern)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No '" & SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN & "' files found in '" _
            & sPath & "'.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        coll.Add sPath & sFileName
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Write data to a jagged array:
    '  - the 1st column will hold the headers (file name without extension)
    '  - the 2nd column will hold the source number of rows
    '    for the final inner loop i.e. 'For dr = 1 To dJag(c, 2)';
    '    this row number is used anyway, to determine the number
    '    of destination rows.
    '  - the 3rd column will hold an array with the source range values
    
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = coll.Count
    Dim dJag As Variant: ReDim dJag(1 To dcCount, 1 To 3)
    Dim OneCell As Variant: ReDim OneCell(1 To 1, 1 To 1) ' if one cell
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sfCell As Range
    Dim slCell As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    Dim swbName As String
    Dim drCount As Long
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim c As Long
    
    For Each Item In coll
        c = c + 1
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(Item, True, True)
        swbName = swb.Name
        ' Write file name without extension.
        dJag(c, 1) = Left(swbName, InStrRev(swbName, ".") - 1)
        Set sws = swb.Worksheets(SOURCE_WORKSHEET_ID)
        If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False
        Set sfCell = sws.Range(SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Set slCell = sfCell.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not slCell Is Nothing Then
            Set srg = sws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
            srCount = srg.Rows.Count
            If srCount > drCount Then drCount = srCount ' determine max row
            ' Write number of rows.
            dJag(c, 2) = srCount
            ' Write data.
            If srCount = 1 Then ' one cell in column
                OneCell(1, 1) = srg.Value
                dJag(c, 3) = OneCell
            Else ' multiple cells in column
                dJag(c, 3) = srg.Value
            End If
        'Else ' no data in column; do nothing
        End If
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just reading
    Next Item
    Set coll = Nothing ' data is in 'dJag'
    
    drCount = drCount + 1 ' + 1 for headers
    
    ' Write the data from the jagged array to the destination array.
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
        
    Dim dr As Long
        
    For c = 1 To dcCount
        ' Write header.
        dData(1, c) = dJag(c, 1)
        ' Write data.
        If Not IsEmpty(dJag(c, 2)) Then
            For dr = 1 To dJag(c, 2)
                dData(dr + 1, c) = dJag(c, 3)(dr, 1) ' + 1 due to headers
            Next dr
        'Else ' no data in column; do nothing
        End If
    Next c
    Erase dJag ' data is in 'dData'
        
    ' Write the data from the destination array to the destination range.
        
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(DESTINATION_WORKSHEET_NAME)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DESTINATION_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Columns imported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```